# one to many with linux command line tools

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a list of pairs like this:

```
12 23
14 54
33 21
12 44
14 54
33 52
```

I'm trying to select all the left-hand values that appear paired with more than one different right-hand value (mother/child relationship for those mothers who has more than one child).  So for these data, I want

```
12 23
12 44
33 21
33 52
```

(the order is not important)

Can I do this with standard Linux text tools?

**Somebody recompose my question with different meaning, I dont know why, his change is completely wrong from the problem point of view. Please revoke your change dont distract others pls.

I just want to select rows where the number of the first column has more than one couple in the second column.
In the result I would like to get the 12 only or width couples 12 23, 12 44**

Comment: grep '^12' works for me...

Comment: sorry but, I mean without using 12

Comment: ??? You want search for something but don't want to search with this search criterea ??? Can you point out what you really want to do?

Comment: search criteria is: finding those numbers from the first column which has more than one different couple (adjacent pair), as I mentioned

Answer (score 2):

```
sort -u filename|awk '{a[$1]++;b[NR]=$0;c[NR]=$1;}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(a[c[i]]>1)print b[i];}'
```

`sort -u` will print only unique lines, and with `awk` print lines what u want.

Comment: The beauty of one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
grep ^12 listfilename
```

Comment: sorry but, I mean without using 12

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution in ***bash***. It also depends on ***echo***, ***cat***, ***cut***, ***sort*** and ***wc***.

First let's re-create the input data file so anyone can quickly test the code:

```
rm input
echo "12 23" >> input
echo "14 54" >> input
echo "33 21" >> input
echo "12 44" >> input
echo "14 54" >> input
echo "33 52" >> input
```

Let's name `a` the first number and `b` the second one.

For each `a` a file named `list_$a` is created and filled with all `b` connected to `a`.

```
while read line; do
  a=$(echo $line | cut -d" " -f1)
  b=$(echo $line | cut -d" " -f2)
  echo $b >> "list_$a"
done < input
```

Then the lists are turned into sets by using the command `sort -u`:

```
for l in list_*; do
  cat $l | sort -u > ${l/list/set}
done
```

For each set file with more than 1 line, let's display each `b` prefixed with `a`:

```
for s in set_*; do
  n=$(cat $s | wc -l)
  if [ "$n" -gt "1" ]; then
    a=${s/set_/}
    while read b; do
      echo "$a $b"
    done < $s
  fi
done
```

The expected output should be displayed:

```
12 23
12 44
33 21
33 52
```

Finally, let's clean the temporary files:

```
rm list_* set_*
```